# Field-derived template names in Django class-based views

Tags: django, django-templates, django-class-based-views

I'm having trouble figuring out how to load a template from a model's field name in Django's new class-based views. Basically I'm looking for the functionality of Django contrib flatpages in my own model like so:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    template_name = CharField(_('Template name'), max_length=255)
```

Time was I'd just lookup the object and then RenderResponse using the template_name field's value. I suppose I could do that with class-based views, but is there are more appropriate way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure where you're having problems, but it sounds like the [SingleTemplateResponseMixin](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/class-based-views/#singleobjecttemplateresponsemixin) would help - it has a `template_name_field` attribute which is set to the name of the field containing the name of the template.

Comment: Thanks, not sure how I missed that in the docs. Though the class-based view docs are a lesson in chasing things around because of all the mixins.